# Is Apple ipad / tablet good for mathematics students?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a math student. I'd like to find out if tablets (iPads, Galaxy Note 10.1) are worth the cost. 
How good are tablets for the purposes of reading textbooks as PDF and writing mathematics with a stylus?

For writing math in TeX, it looked like the Android app store was in need of a [TeX editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TeXEditor.TeXEditor_full&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5UZVhFZGl0b3IuVGVYRWRpdG9yX2Z1bGwiXQ..), so I had all the fun writing one which renders the TeX as on math.stackexchange, and can also export to PDF.

Comment: Please do not close. Upvotes on the response and on the question clearly show it is of interest to the community.

Comment: I have a Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 (about 1.5 years old) and echo everything @Qiaochu says: Great for reading, but not for writing. However, if you aren't set on getting an iPad, consider the new Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1, which is specifically designed for note taking. One of the major demographics Samsung is aiming at with this product is students, and the CNN and CNET reviews are positive, so it could be worth your time to pop into an electronics store and try it out for yourself.

Comment: Also, about it being worth the cost: My tablet has paid for itself a few times over in the amount saved in purchasing textbooks and printing out my lecturers notes. I carry around a ridiculous library filled with heaps great books in almost every field of mathematics and I love browsing through them all. I should probably take Qiaochu's advice and force myself to work through the essential ones by deleting the others.

Comment: @RagibZaman after trying the new iPad with a decent stylus, I can concur with others that iPad's not so great for writing. So I will probably try the Note 10.1. The reviews seem good.
http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-10-1-32GB/dp/B007M506WS

Comment: I have found iAnnotate PDF ($10) very useful for reading math papers, and especially for annotating drafts of my own papers. But I don't know how useful it would be for reading textbooks.

Comment: While I can't speak for iPads, I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII and I regularly read mathematics on it using the built-in pdf reader. I can download files at will and just read them on the train. Writing mathematics on the other hand is still strictly reserved for pen and paper for me.

Comment: I have to say that I wouldn't consider using an iPad to write mathematics. I just feel that the screen is too small. I have issues writing small as well. However, I'd say that it's a true pleasure to use it for reading textbooks. I have my entire collection of books in iBooks.

Comment: @TomChurch the problem with iAnnotate is that it misses the search over all contents in documents, I hence like PDF Expert much more. I can download 1000 documents and search a single word over them with PDF Expert -app -- and it does it!

Comment: @Limitless that is right unless good app and good stylus. Google Jot -stylus and UPad, they are amazing for bezier-zoom-tiny writing. Jot also works in Android tablets although much nicer in iPad with better display and no lag.

Comment: @T.Webster I wish u tried Jot, it is the closest you can get to pen on touch-screen, passively. It is far better in precision to usual styluses, it works in any capacitive touch-screen. See my updated answer.

Comment: @RagibZaman my brother's Samsung galaxy had extra lag and poor screen, only 5 months old. He just changed to iPad after my writing below -- iPad quality is apparently awesome although so many bugs. As for Samsung, you need to jailbreak it to make it faster. Even then I would use iPad. Anyway, get a pen-like stylus with screen-protector to make ur writing much more precise.

Comment: "As a math student"? No. Reading .pdf's is nice on an iPad. That's the extent of good things one can say. There are other nice things, some of which have been detailed below, but none are worth the price of admission.

If you want an iPad, get one, but know that an iPad runs neither emacs nor vim, and is thus a toy.

Comment: @GunnarMagnusson Vim is in App-store but cannot find ESC in it. iPad misses the traditional fs but you can use iSSH to use Vim. have you tested the Vim -app? I have but haven't understood it yet.

Comment: **[Update]** Use this thread [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221991/android-devices-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) for Android to keep things focused.

Comment: @RagibZaman I intend to buy [Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1](http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-10-1-32GB/dp/B007M506WS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356251528&sr=8-1&keywords=samsung+galaxy+note+10.1) and would like to know if you still stick to your earlier opinion you have mentioned in the comments. If so, I would order it right away. Also, is it self contained i.e. does it come with stylus, the software needed etc? Thanks!

Comment: @Marvis My earlier opinion was about my own Galaxy Tab 10.1, I have not used a Note 10.1. I would expect that the Note is at least as good as the Tab in the aspects I mentioned above (the Note should also be great for reading textbooks, notes, browsing the web is also good) but I have no idea about the writing aspect.

Comment: @Marvis If possible, I strongly recommend testing out a unit from a store or a friend before ordering it. The Note is self contained, it comes with stylus and software for note taking etc, though some 3rd parties may have produced better software for download in the Android market (usually free, sometimes not). For example, I prefer "EBookDroid" as my reader since it reads book djvu and pdf formats, as opposed to the standard Adobe reader which only reads pdfs.

Comment: @RagibZaman Thanks for your immediate response. I am mainly looking for a good device to take notes. As you have suggested, I will try at a store before making a final decision.

Comment: OP's question has been edited to make it cover all tablets.

Answer (score 48):

I can only speak from personal experience here, so don't take anything I say as a universal statement about doing math with iPads.

1. Reading math on an iPad is great. I've been using my iPad to read during meals, at cafes, and in other places where it's more convenient because of its size than taking out my laptop, and it also has substantially better battery life (not too big an issue now but it will be very useful the next time I take a long flight / train ride / bus ride). My current setup is that I only transfer reading material that I actually plan on reading soon (rather than my entire library), so the somewhat limited selection forces me to actually read what I was planning to read. Earlier I had a long backlog of things I was planning on reading, but it was so large that it was intimidating to start. As far as specific apps, GoodReader is good for .pdfs but doesn't read .djvus; for the latter you can use Stanza.
2. Writing math on an iPad is not great. I don't have a stylus myself, but a friend of mine who tried taking notes with a stylus found it both too slow and too imprecise, and based on my experiences I'm not surprised. This may change depending on the stylus but not, I think, substantially. If you want to TeX on an iPad, the best option I'm aware of is TeX Touch, which I haven't tried because I find typing on an iPad annoying compared to typing on a laptop.
3. Non-obvious advantage: it is very easy to draw mathematical graphics in some iPad app (I use Paper) and not terribly difficult to include them in LaTeX'ed notes (such as [these](http://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/Notes/274/)). As a general rule, iPad apps heavily prioritize ease of use, so I didn't have to learn how to use a sophisticated tool: I just downloaded an app and started drawing. I think in general most mathematics could benefit from an increased use of graphics and I'm happy to have a tool that allows me to use graphics more easily.

My standard answer to your last question, which is not specific to iPads, is that mathematics which is typed up rather than handwritten is 1) more legible and 2) much, much easier to copy and distribute. But this is an argument for doing mathematics electronically, not an argument for doing mathematics with an iPad.

Comment: *Tex Touch* is useful when you have no laptop right now, and you have to modify some typos in your beamer which has to be presented in 15 minutes, but fortunately you are in a wifi-zone. Typing with iPad even with a bluetooth keyboard is somewhat annoying, and moreover this app requires network access because the compile process takes place in a remote server, not in your iPad.

Comment: The iPad is not designed for stylus input. PC tablets (a dying breed!) are better, but I still find it hard to get used to...

Comment: Also on the advantage of typing over handwriting : you can easily search, modify, reorganize or repurpose content, you also have virtually unlimited memory to store it. But of course, handwriting also has its advantages such as immediacy and intuitiveness (which often leads to more graphs).

Comment: +1. The "My current setup..." part of your first paragraph seems to be a huge piece of advice for me, thanks!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I saw your notes and was very impressed by them. You write above, however, that the iPad has some disadvantages as far as taking notes is concerned, so I'm curious as to how you created those notes. I understand that the graphics were done in Paper on the iPad, but do you take notes by hand at first and then later digitize them?

Comment: @Zhen: Actually they are being resurrected now. There are Intel Atom based hybrids (tablets + keyboard dock) waiting for the release of Windows 8 to be sent to the stores... Lenovo ThinkPad Tablet 2/Asus Vivo Tab/etc. many come with a Wacom digitizer pen which I believe will be great for writing notes in real time.

Comment: @Michael: I took the notes on my laptop (I type much faster than I write), but I drew the diagrams by hand and then redrew them on my iPad.

Comment: As for the "taking with you". You can put the files in a dropbox folder and the iPad client synchronizes them when you need.

Comment: Also, your drawings are pretty damn good if you don't have a stylus... Also with.

Comment: Typed notes are certainly better than handwritten ones, but surely they take much longer to create?

Comment: Which "Paper" you mean? There are "Paper 53" -app, Paper -app and other apps. "Bamboo Paper" -app and "Paper 53" -app look cool but "Paper" -app is poor by that name. Could you clarify?

Comment: Two disadvantages of Stanza worth noting: 1) it is no longer supported by Amazon and is liable to break in a future iOS update (it broke once in iOS 5 but was patched for presumably the last time).  2) It does not natively support DjVu but converts it to PDF through a very time-consuming and space-consuming process.

Comment: I am using iPad to read my tetbooks. Also, i am doimg math homework on my iPad using Notability app. It is inefficient to take notes with, but good enough for homework.

Comment: Have you tried Jot -stylus? I cannot fully understand your comment about slowness and inaccucrasy, could you clarify this? I know most styluses are poor bulky rubber products but Jot is more like a pen. It may work for you. More info [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/si/topics/the_stylus_reviews_thread_which_stylus_helps_you_be_more_procreative).

Comment: **[TeX Touch]** When I tried this product, it kept crashing and lagging. The only viable product I think is TeX Writer, compiler inside the app. You can get full Texlive to it through dropbox, I am very happy about that. I need no laptop to write articles, I need only iPad and the keyboard. How about you?

Comment: Mathematics that's typed up is better, once you've figured out what you want to say.  At that point I'll type it up in LaTeX.  But exploration, finding a solution to a problem, developing a proof from scratch requires an easy, easy interface--for me, at least.  Such as pen and paper.  Except that I don't want to use pen and paper.

Answer (score 39):

You require two things: good stylus and good app. I also like to have stand but more about apps and accessories [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/257329#257329). Before buying any Apple product, please, acknowledge the below limitations.

**Limitations**

> - Linux users should check whether they can do everything they need with Chromebook and Android phone because Apple discriminates you in many things such as no iTunes support. This basically means that you cannot get backups and the use of iOS devices is very painful and slow. Some apps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/257329#257329) such as iCab are meant to circumvent the Apple lock -- Apple makes it as hard as possible to use iPad without OS X so downloading lecture slides to iPad is a big brainy problem -- really you cannot download lecture-slides to iPad without special app (ridiculous)!
> - Low-income students should not buy the oldest OS X units because Apple stops the support after about 5 years, it is even poorer with iOS devices.

**iPad for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?**

> - Real-time TeXing [here](https://stacky.net/wiki/index.php?title=Advice_on_real-time_TeXing) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/most-useful-latex-macros-help-me-to-understand-a-statement-with-psfrac)
> - [A digital notebook for Mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118856/a-digital-notebook-for-mathematics)
> - [What software and/or language to use to take Math lecture notes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17805/what-software-and-or-language-to-use-to-take-math-lecture-notes)
> - [Android devices for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221991/android-devices-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand)

[image]

*In order to write like with a pen, you need either a screen-protector or a very sharp stylus. Perhaps, it is the reason why Jot and the small DX-118368 stylus [here](https://www.dx.com/p/stylish-stylus-pen-for-ipad-iphone-black-2013410) are my favorite styluses.*

[image]

*iPad is somewhat laggy in comparison to powerful computer with good GPU and Wacom board. Jot scratches the screen. Many imprecise bulky styluses but my favorite stylus [here](https://www.dx.com/p/stylish-stylus-pen-for-ipad-iphone-black-2013410) -- the stylus with the smallest width in the picture. If I had to choose two styluses, I would still go with a Jot stylus and DX-118368 stylus [here](https://www.dx.com/p/stylish-stylus-pen-for-ipad-iphone-black-2013410).*

[image]

*The essential apps are Notes Mobile app, UPAD app, TeX Writer app, GoodReader and PDF Expert app. You can see how search over scholars and academic papers in the picture with Papers app. FrameArtist is for collegues like in this writing. Things work the best if you have iTunes and at least iPad, bottom pictures with iPhone -- yes the same apps work over iPad and iPhone. If you have to study in noisy environments, please, consider neutralizing the noise with things such as SimplyNoise white-brown-pink-noise-generator app and SHOUTcast app's CINEMIX radio, free relaxing sounds to hide noises and to help concentration -- more about silencing noises [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131214062348/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/1509752/white-noise-sources-for-concentration-while-programming), hope the tips and hints help your studying!*

**Further information**

> 1. How to compare documents in iPad [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69344/pdf-software-to-read-many-documents-side-by-side-in-ipad)
> 2. How to search over all content in iPad [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68849/ios-app-to-search-all-content-in-pdf-files)
> 3. Editing material on iPad [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73214/editing-of-material-such-as-pdfs-in-ios-for-vizualisation) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69659/ipad-pdf-software-to-edit-merge-annotate-etc-well-pdf-documents-like-in-deskto)
> 4. How to read the same book together on many iPads [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66296/how-to-read-the-same-book-together-on-many-ipads)
> 5. App to add photos to LaTex document with iPad's camera [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74652/app-to-add-photos-to-latex-document-with-ipad-camera)
> 6. iPad's accessories and some apps for education purposes [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/257329#257329).

Comment: I didn't know that the iPad can be used to procreate. Can't wait to try it!

Comment: This is a copy of Math on iPad for dummies. I'll sue you for copyright infringement!

Comment: @hhh I'm only kidding.

Comment: The [relevance to mathematics] to [words and pictures] ratio of this answer is very low...

Comment: Looks good.  I mean, I didn't downvote this post, while 29 others have upvoted.  Clearly the community finds your post very useful.  All I meant to express was a personal preference for a clearer relation to mathematical life.

Comment: Based on this question and answer, I went with GoodNotes, Adonit Jot Pro, an Apple wireless keyboard, and TeX Writer. I use the Jot Pro and GoodNotes for tutoring and certain types of studying, the keyboard and TeX Writer for more serious work. The combination and flexibility is impressive, and my students love it. I also recommend a Power Support Anti-glare film for protection and to cut down on glare and fingerprints: http://www.powersupportusa.com/accessories/ipad-2/hd-anti-glare-film.html  Thanks hhh!

Comment: The video is *very* helpful, because it suggests that writing with a stylus on an iPad, even in the best case, is not at all close to writing on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 24):

I've had my iPad for just over a year and it is now integral to my life as a mathematician.  I read books and papers on it, I annotate work on it (making it far easier to comment on students' theses: scribble on it and send it straight back instead of printing-commenting-scanning), I also write my mathematics on it as well.  I use it to present my lectures (when doing these as beamer presentations).  And now I can even write TeX articles on it with no need for connectivity.  I find it easier now to take my iPad around with me than a laptop: whilst there are things that are easier on a laptop, there are things possible on an iPad (or other tablet, I guess) that aren't possible on a laptop so I prefer to take my iPad than my laptop.

In more detail, here are the applications that I use.  I can't say that others aren't good as I haven't downloaded every variant of, say, PDF reader (though I did do a bit of research into annotation but that was some time ago and applications change rapidly).

1. **GoodReader**.  This is the application I use for reading and annotating PDFs.  Its annotation capabilities are getting better but aren't the best.  However, it has various features that make it excellent for reading.  One of the most useful is that you can crop a page to a particular view so the big margins typical of LaTeX documents don't use up valuable screen space.
2. **GoodNotes**.  This is the application I use for writing mathematics and for displaying PDF presentations.  I use a stylus, and I find it quite easy to use.  A stylus isn't quite as easy as a pen on paper (the resistance is a bit different), but being able to organise my notes more than compensates for that.  It has a "zoom" mode which makes it easy to write with accuracy.  The presentation mode is "clean" in that only the PDF and any annotations are shown.
3. **TeX Writer**.  There are now two applications that can TeX a document on the iPad itself (no cloud or internet connection needed).  My opinion is that TeX Writer is the superior of the two.
4. **Codea**.  This is a programming application.  I use it for doing simulations and demonstrations in my lectures.

I've written a little about this on the TeX-SX blog:

- http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/i-tex-therefore-ipad/
- http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/i-tex-therefore-ipad-reloaded/

So I find that I disagree with the other answers (to date) in their caution.  The more I use my iPad, the more I find that it just "fits" in with my workflow and have none of the hesitation that the others have.  I don't think that it would work for everyone, but it is certainly possible that it will prove a benefit.

*Added in Edit* Here's some screenshots:

GoodNotes:

[image: Notes taken with GoodNotes]

Also, the annotations on my course notes this year have been done using GoodNotes.  http://mathsnotes.math.ntnu.no/mathsnotes/show/lecture+notes+2011 (switched to iPad part-way through this course) and http://mathsnotes.math.ntnu.no/mathsnotes/show/TMA4115+lecture+notes+2012

Codea: You can see some of the things I've done on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/user/mapstacey It should be fairly obvious which things were designed for lectures.

*One more thing 2012-11-16* Regarding transferring files, my iPad is not jailbroken and I can easily transfer files between it and either my Mac or my Linux computer.  Most applications use Dropbox, or if I can connect via USB then I use a library called `libimobiledevice` which gives me access to applications' "Documents" directories.

Comment: There (TeX Writer) I have an advantage: I'm a beta-tester so I know what's coming.  Two things: with the editor, the double row of extra keys is invaluable.  With the compiler, I can add the entirety of TeXLive if I want to (and have done so).  I have no idea which packages are bundled with TeXPad and have been unable to find out, making it practically useless to me.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot one of the most important things.  TeX Writer gives me the full log file.  TeXPad gives me a summary.

Comment: The double row of extra keys is in TeX Writer.

Comment: No, not as yet, though I'm considering it now that I can run TeX on it.

Comment: @hhh I don't understand your comment, it doesn't seem directed at me.

Comment: Sorry I directed the feature request directly to Li, more [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/A4NDuhFCMAAxXA4.jpg:large).

Comment: Which stylus do you use? Have you compared other styli?

Comment: @deiga I use the cheapest stylus I could find - don't remember the make.  There are instructions for building ones own on the internet.  I've not used any other.  One has to learn to use it, but once done it's good enough for taking notes and annotating stuff.

Comment: Not to duplicate comments, but I want to +1 GoodNotes and TeX Writer. Thanks for your recommendations.

Comment: The graphic of a page of text in GoodNotes is, all by itself, worth all of the answers on this page (and they are very helpful).  That's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a great fan of the iPad, which does certain things brilliantly. It can't replace a laptop but having one in addition certainly enhances your digital life hugely.

On the question of the additional cost -- to get that out of the way first -- think what one cup of coffee five days a week over two years costs (even that terrible cheap coffee from the student coffee place!). Compare the cost of an iPad (you won't need more than wifi connectivity). Ask yourself: will you get a coffee's worth of value from the iPad most days? The answer seems obvious to me :-)

OK, as to maths: *Reading* PDFs is a brilliant experience on an iPad (and DjVU isn't at all bad). I would very much rather read maths books and papers on the iPad than on a laptop screen. And this seems a common experience (on one bit of independent research I saw, people were approaching indifference between physical books and reading on an iPad, but rated either far above reading on a computer screen). Minor annotation on the PDFs (highlighting, very brief notes to self) works very well too e.g. in GoodReader. And of course all your other reading, whether is classical novels, or newspaper websites, or whatever, is also vastly nicer on an iPad than on a computer. And then there are all the non-reading things that you can do with it (sitting in a cafe doing your emails, facebook, etc.).

*Writing* maths is quite different though, and after experimenting early on, I found that good old pen and paper still works very much better for notes taken in the heat of the moment in lectures/talks etc. In fact your note taking really should be a two-phase project anyway. (1) You write rough notes "live" in the lecture, and then (2) you should write up the notes afterwards, consulting textbooks, classmates etc. until you are sure you have got things really clear. Stage (1) is for nearly everyone best done the old-fashioned way; stage (2) is best done on a laptop running a LaTeX installation. At neither stage is using an iPad a good choice.

So, yes, go for an iPad as a terrific addition to the laptop which you'll get a great deal of use from, even for work/study. But it isn't all purpose tool, and in particular isn't a serious writing platform, in the way your laptop is.

Comment: DjVU is bad, only Stanza simplest works -- other apps are broken: search sxcks and OCR is nowhere. Which DjVU -app you are referring to with `"DjVU isn't at all bad"`? More specific info in this thread [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63282/ipad-good-djvu-reader-with-search-and-easy-uploading-without-itunes), save some money before buying the inferior DjVU apps, most just junk. iPad is not realy for reading books, I use Kindle for reading books (better for my eyes). iPad works far better during lectures...though I also have laptop/android/etc. iPad camera helps note-taking.

Answer (score 4):

I use a Kindle DX for reading PDFs, which it's absolutely great at.  It's e-ink instead of LCD, so it's not hurting your eyes when you're reading off of it for long stretches.  It's way less interactive than most things, though -- the screen can only update one a second or so, so no animation or anything.

Comment: I think this is a good point (even though not answering the question in iPad sense) +1 -- we should seriously narrow down this thread or make it more specific to mathematics. Where is iPad good and where it is not? iPad is not clearly good in reading if you cannot get a lecture-slide to it without external app. Is there any better substitute to it? Can you read for example homework and lecture-slide side-by-side with Kindle DX or some other product? Battery life? Someone should make some table about different products...for comparison.

Comment: I tried to make some sense to this by this thread [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257417/small-technical-device-to-read-side-by-side-homeworks-and-lecture-slides). I tried to write it in electronics-agnostic way. It asks a specific feature in small electronics devices to do homeworks more efficiently without carrying a large laptop all around.

Comment: OP's question has been edited to broaden it to all tablets.

Answer (score 3):

DjVu Reader had annoying bugs but it works fine now, as far as I know. The last news I had was that Stanza produces PDF from DJVU in order to  read it, it has to be done on a computer, before transferring to iPad, the process of production of the pdf is long and the pdf file produced is around 60 Mb or more ... Is it still true ?

Comment: Ebookdroid is great for android devices. It used to be pretty buggy, and you have to install an extra font pack, but once this is done it is great for reading texts.  It can handle djvu and pdf just fine and will hold your place from when you were last reading.  It also has a recent books section so you don't always have to dig through your whole library.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is biased towards physical things. The answer continues from this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/204393/5902).*

iPad is pretty stupid thing without a good stand to help reading -- it is easy to damage its covers for instance in the bag. It is annoying to read with a stand that is falling. I have tested all kind of iPad things such as SmarterStand (I don't like it) and iPad with aluminium cover-keyboard (I don't like it) -- I use iPad mostly for reading and carrying around so a good leather protector stand is very-very useful.

It may not matter but my [apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hcu6.jpg): I have worked quite a bit to work with iPad a bit like an office but nowadays I use it mostly for reading books, newspapers, occasional server maintenance and dictionaries. Office products are still very young and hard-to-use, it takes some time to get ice-breakers.

**Apps**

> I. Misc such as **ProCreate** for fast recretional notes and iCab Mobile if no OS X.
>
> II. **Documents** or PDF Expert app: they have a search over all content so you can search for an arbitrary word let say in Homeworks
>
> III. **iBook** for reading (I earlier used GoodReader and PDF Expert for this but not anymore because iBook/OS X far better option for me now)

### **Accessories**

> [image]
>
> - Protective **45 degrees' Stand** to see iPad upright like [here](http://dx.com/p/70119?r=36798618)
> - Neodymium magnets [here](http://dx.com/p/4248?r=36798618), plastic tape and Origami keep the Jot Pro attached below the keyboard, not working with Jot Classic because of lacking magnets.
> - You can create a magnetized stylus with the DX light-laser-good-head stylus 81442 and the magnets by inserting magnets above the battery container, then you get the best laser-point led stylus so far on the market and it can be attached to iPad's cover similarly to Maglus. I don't like Maglus, I like the laser-pointer-stylus much more [here](http://dx.com/p/81442?r=36798618). I get flashlight-laser-stylus in one thing, it is very useful during lectures and in group-working.

Comment: Livescribe turns note-taking into timewise notes with historical view, this would be pretty cool in iPad -- does it exist?

Comment: OCR: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3731/extraction-of-math-expressions-with-ocr-from-scanned-photos

Comment: There is currently no good comparison app, only Side-by-Side, so hard to read two papers such as homework and lecture-slide side-by-side....the way I do it now is to merge many PDFs so easier to read as one.

Comment: CloudOn works for editing Windows files. iAnnotate displays math-formulae correctly without editing.

Comment: **[Update]** If you have OSX, Calibre with iBook beats Readle's products in reading experience. If you have iPad and Kidnle, Kindle app is pretty cool because you can turn your iPad into "Kindle" -- now forgetting PDF Expert in the favour of Apple's iBook, Kindle and perhaps Documents.