# How can I add equations to services such as Keynote or Pages in iPad?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

Mathematical formulae are very poor in services such as Windows Word, Keynote, Pages -- or many times totally missing, not to speak about compability -problems. So how can I create and add formulae to such services in iPad?

Answer (score 1):

*I answer here about this case, to keep this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand/204393#204393) more focused.*

I have probably tested now all apps and -- the only apps I can recommend are MathBot and TeX Equation. Unfortunately, the TeX Equation has a small bug as can be seen in the examples. Below you can see how poorer products such as TeXit work. The worst case is with Equations -app, the one above TeXit in the photo.

[image]

**MathJax VS TeX Equation**

> There is bug currently in TeX equation that we are trying to resolve [here](https://twitter.com/litchiedev/status/253657970242633730). When this bug is resolved, I can happily recommend TeX Equation.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> *Sorry about the bug in one of the pictures, it is a bug with ProCreate -- I  filled it [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/si/topics/bug_with_painting_odd_cuts).*