# Increased Math Productivity on Mobile Devices

Tags: soft-question, education

I have been answering questions on Math.SE for a (relatively) short time now, and I have found that answering questions on my Android phone is somewhat of a nightmare. I end up commenting much of the time and doing so in ASCII when I know I could help the OP more fully. As such, I determined that the following two things would greatly help me increase my productivity

$\;\;1.\;\;$ A good keyboard for MathJax/LaTeX style editing. My current keyboard doesnt work well with the SE Application as it has necessary keys in poor locations, such as the backslash being two menus away. With such a strong community I feel that the SE network must have a good keyboard for this... I mean, the network was created around programming.

$\;\;2.\;\;$ A decent editor for Math Equations on the go. While traveling I often have ideas I desire to write down, and I love to record ideas in MathJax when I have a computer nearby, generally on StackEdit... I feel that the effort that goes into encoding each line makes me think harder through the problem and check my work. However, this is much more difficult on mobile where I have thus far been limited to ASCII

I have looked for similar questions (which I am sure are out there but under very different naming schemes). So far I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206169/how-can-i-add-equations-to-services-such-as-keynote-or-pages-in-ipad/206170#206170) for iPads and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221991/android-devices-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) for Androids, although the first is irrelevant for my platform and the second didn't seem to have a quality response in the slightest. I did find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand), which has a fantastic number of answers, but only tablets (specifically iPads) are mentioned in any of the answers.

Comment: Backslash key should be available after long keypress on `/`.

Comment: Should this be in the meta stack?

Comment: @Bob1123 I considered putting it there... it felt borderline so I was unsure.

Comment: @Bob1123 Looks more like [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @Normal If you feel that I would get more answer there than I would love to have it migrated. The question was more targeted at fellow Math.SE users to discover what tricks they have found, a specialization I feared I would lose on another site such as Software Recommendations. (Also, my go-to keyboard doesn't even support long keypresses. Anything would be better at this point)

Comment: See [Offline LaTeX Editor and compiler for Android](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20227#23242); and there are plenty of questions about keyboards tagged [android] there.

Comment: Betta on Meta. :)