# Android devices for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?

Tags: soft-question

*This thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) about iPad is getting Android -answers that belong to other thread.*

I am interested in things such as real-time TeXing, LaTeX recognition, writing math by styluses/keyboards, teaching -- anything that can be useful for mathematicians and students alike to work.

So can you use Android devices for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?

Comment: Really? [android] **and** [electronics] tags?

Comment: I suggest you bring this up to a meta thread. I certainly can't see the appeal in any of these tags (the [ipad] tag included). Note that you are the sole user of all these tags...

Comment: @AsafKaragila perhaps we should remove the comments because this issue is now solved, thanks for your input!

Comment: At this point the linked [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) has been edited to cover all tablets.

Answer (score 2):

Because most Android devices lack proper screens, precision writing with things such as Jot Pro do not work. Your best bet for precision writing with Android is to get a Thinkpad x220 tablet or similar. More about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/ipad-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand). I use Maglus stylus in Android devices because the precision tools do not work. Then I use finger-writing tools below, free and good enough to have an old Android phone for casual uses such as finding certain Greek alphabets.

**Apps with Finger-writing**

The apps below do not work with precision writing with Jot because most Android devices do not have good-enough display. Currently, the only way to test whether Jot works with a display is to test it: even certain better-than-retina-displays do not work with Jot.

> **I. Detexify [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coolcherrytrees.software.detexify&hl=en)**
>
> > > [image]
>
> **II. OCR MyScript -calculator [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visionobjects.calculator&hl=en)**
>
> > > [image]

**Accessories**

> I use Gooseneck 1/4, Balljoint 1/4 and camera-phone-mount [here](http://dx.com/p/48529?r=36798618) to have my hands free while working with things. Sometimes, I use a macro flash for near-photographs with a DSL camera for very precise photographs. Phone-camera works however for casual photos such as note-taking.
>
> [image]

*P.s. For future, there is a software called Screenshot UX [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liveov.shotux&hl=en) for sharing sheetshots in Android devices but it requires rooted phone. By this tool, you can easily show and recommend apps.*