# Writing lecture notes on a tablet

Tags: soft-question

I'm a graduate student concerned with taking lecture notes from courses I attend. I can type in real-tie in latex (except in tikz) but I find writing sometimes more intuitive (and using laptop is clumsy in some lecture halls as well). Since [this question was asked many years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand), the technology has massively changed.

What do you think on writing on ipad pro? Is the "usual" ipad enough (with an appropriate stylo)? Is there any change for the android tablets?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do it with my iPad. The obvious problem is the speed. You cannot write on iPad as fast as you can with a pen and paper.